# Calculate average from CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am new to Python and im trying to calculate some averages.

I have a CSV with the following data:

```
Network,Result
Network 1,100
Network 2,200
Network 3,300
Network 1,101
Network 2,202
Network 3,303
```

How can i calculate the average for Network 1,Network 2 and Network 3 and create another CSV with the following data:

```
Network,Average
Network 1,105
Network 2,201
Network 3,301.5
```

Is seems pretty easy, but im breaking my head over this.

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `100.5`?

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: https://datatofish.com/use-pandas-to-calculate-stats-from-an-imported-csv-file/

Comment: How do you plan to read the CSV files? You can solve that with pure Python, using the `csv` module, using `numpy`, using `pandas`...

Comment: You can get the average of a column by creating a pandas dataframe from your csv data and then `df['Result'].mean()`. You can subset by column by `df[df['Network] == 1]` etc. Recommend reading a intro to pandas guide [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)

(df 
.groupby('Network')['Result'].mean()
.rename(columns={"Result": "Average"})
.reset_index()
.to_csv("agg.csv", index=False))

     Network  Average
0  Network 1   100.5
1  Network 2   201.0
2  Network 3   301.5
```

Comment: This is using the pandas library. You can get the csv into pandas with 
`import pandas as pd` then
`df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)`

Comment: Op also wants the column renamed to "Average". add the line `.rename(columns={"Result": "Average"})` before .to_csv() to achieve this

Comment: Why do you `reset_index` and don't output it later?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa not sure if I understood your question

Comment: `reset_index` is not necessary, since the index is not output anyway. It does not _hurt_ either, but since this is a pretty long chain of commands we can drop the unnecessary ones to simplify.

Comment: Thanks, this works! But i used the solution under my comment, since the data is from an SQL database. I converted to data from SQL to CSV, but with the solution underneath, i do not have to do that anymore. Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

If you work with databases a lot, you might prefer writing SQL instead of reinventing the wheel. I find this to be the easiest to understand:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

mydata = pd.DataFrame([
['Network 1',100]
,['Network 2',200]
,['Network 3',300]
,['Network 1',101]
,['Network 2',202]
,['Network 3',303]]
,columns=['Network','Result'])

mysql = """
select Network,avg(Result) as avgresult
from mydata
group by Network
"""

print(ps.sqldf(mysql))
```

returns:

```
     Network  avgresult
0  Network 1      100.5
1  Network 2      201.0
2  Network 3      301.5
```

Comment: Thnx! I used this one to fix my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Pandas provide various methods of reading data from Files.

`read_csv()` is one of them

Here is the solution to your task.

```
# Importing Pandas Library
import pandas as pd
# Reading the CSV file from the File system.
csv = pd.read_csv("data/temp1.csv")
# Your statement says your need unique Network data and average over the values.
# For your learning, you can add multiple column names in groupby clause according to your requirement. 
# You can also use different aggregation like count, sum etc. in agg function. Again its a list hence you can pass multiple aggregations at the same time.
newds = csv.groupby(['Network'])['Result'].agg(['mean']).reset_index()
# Finally converting your dataset to csv file and saving it into the File System. 
newds.to_csv('new_csv.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
with open("data.csv", newline='', mode='r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    networks = defaultdict(lambda: [0,0])
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 1:
            continue
        else:
            network_num, value = row[1].split(",")
            networks[network_num][0] += int(value)
            networks[network_num][1] += 1
    with open("answer.csv", newline='', mode="w") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        writer.writerow(["Network", "Average"])
        for k,v in networks.items():
            average = v[0] / v[1]
            writer.writerow([f'Network {k}', average])
```

output:

```
Network,Average
Network 1,100.5
Network 2,201.0
Network 3,301.5
```

this will output a csv file in the format you want.
**defaultdict** is a datatype that is similar to a dictionary, except if you attempt to access a key that does not exist yet, a default value is provided for that key so you don't get a key error.

Comment: Why are you using `delimiter=' '` when the delimiter is comma? Lots of unnecessary work.